AWS s3 bucket presigned url download error - SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING
I am using presigned urls to download images from my s3 bucket. This is how I generate the presigned url:
boto_client.generate_presigned_url(
            "get_object",
            Params={
                "Bucket": bucket,
                "Key": key,
            },
            ExpiresIn=36000,  # 10 hours
        )

To download the image from presigned url I am using plain js fetch or requests.get, eg.:
response = requests.get(presigned_url)
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

I am processing around 100k requests per hour and most of the time everything works great, but sometimes I can't download the image with the following error:
"\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000issl.SSLEOFError:
 [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)"
DDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool
(host='bucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
 /my_path/8fa39771.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AWSAccessKeyId&Signature=Signature&Expires=1715552122 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in 
violation
of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))

Do you know what could potentially cause the issue? Only around 5-10% of requests fail with above errors, so it doesn't happen very often. What's more the issue started happening around a week ago. Before that I have never seen such errors
I tried looking for answers on google, but I haven't found any similar questions nor answers
